# c3 bar chart Y axis value with fixed value

Tags: php, jquery, html, charts, c3.js

I am  working on c3 chart and I need to make my Y axis to be showing value 1,2,3,4 but instead it shows 1,2 only.

Code I use:

```
c3.generate({
    bindto: '#stocked2',
    data:{
        columns: [
        ['A', 1.8], 
        ['B', 1.6], 
        ['C', 1.7]
        ],
        colors:{
            data1: '#1ab394',
        },
        type: 'bar',
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
            tick: {
                values: [1, 2, 3, 4]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for so many answers, I got a solution for the above question which I posted. Just sharing here the answer used to solve. Thanks for your time.

```
  c3.generate({
    bindto: '#stocked2',
    data:{
        columns: [
        ['A', 1.8], 
        ['B', 1.6], 
        ['C', 1.7]
        ],
        colors:{
            data1: '#1ab394',
        },
        type: 'bar',
      },
        axis: {
            y: {
                min: 1,
                max: 4,
                tick: {
                    values: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see I used min and max to solve y axis.